# MailChimp API Get Subscribers ammount

Tags: api, mailchimp

I have been looking at the mailchimp api, and am wondering how to display the live ammount of subscribers to a list, is this possible? And is it possible to have this counter LIVE? I.e as users join, the number increases in real time?

EDIT:

I have been getting used to the API slightly...

after using Drewm's mailchimp php wrapper its starting to make more sense...

I have so far

```
   // This is to tell WordPress our file requires Drewm/MailChimp.php. 
require_once( 'src/Drewm/MailChimp.php' );
// This is for namespacing since Drew used that. 
use \Drewm;

// Your Mailchimp API Key 
$api = 'APIKEY'; 
$id = 'LISTID'; 
// Initializing the $MailChimp object
$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($api);

$member_info = $MailChimp->call('lists/members', array(
    'apikey' => $api,
    'id' => $id // your mailchimp list id here 
    )
  );
```

But not sure how to display these values, it's currently just saying 'array' when I echo $member_info, this maybe completly because of my ignorance in PHP. Any advice to s

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be old, but maybe this will help someone else looking for this. Latest versions of API and PHP Files.

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($api_key);
$data = $MailChimp->get('lists');

print_r($data);// view output

$total_members = $data['lists'][0]['stats']['member_count'];
$list_id = $data['lists'][0]['id'];
```

$data['lists'][0] = First list. If you have more, then it would be like $data['lists'][1] ect...

And to get a list of members from a list:

```
$data = $MailChimp->get("lists/$list_id/members");

print_r($data['members']);// view output

foreach($data['members'] as $member){
    $email = $member['email_address'];
    $added = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($member['timestamp_opt'])); 
    // I use reverse dates for sorting in a *datatable* so it properly sorts by date
}
```

You can view the **print_r** output to get what you want to get.